# Microsoft account alias decommissioning‏

Tags: outlook.com

When Hotmail aliases began I got an email 'k***s@live.com'. It was a free address. I received and sent emails using that and it worked well. A few days a go I got an email from Microsoft account titled "Microsoft account alias decommissioning‏":

> Microsoft account
>
> We want to inform you that an error occurred in our routing
>   information and mail sent to your alias (K***s@live.com) may have been
>   delivered to another customer with the same address. Unfortunately,
>   this alias was already in use by another customer and we should not
>   have allowed you to create the alias.    In order to fix this issue
>   going forward, we are decommissioning the alias (K___s@live.com).  We
>   regret the error and the inconvenience.
>
> We have now rectified the situation and removed the alias from your
>   account. If you want to add different alias to your account you can do
>   so here: https://account.live.com/names/Manage . Otherwise, there is
>   no further action required.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The Microsoft account team

But the email address is still free or at least is not functioning.

Why did this happen?

The email address is short and convenient.

Is it stolen or is there a special Microsoft email address policy?

Is there a way to recover that?

I was waiting for an important email with that address.

Comment: You may want to send an update email to the person you're expecting the important email from in the meantime

Comment: There's no such person. That address does not receive any email. Any email to that address returns immediately. Either it's free (or microsoft confiscated it as reserved address).